# Two underscore symbols in a type definition

Tags: ocaml

I am learning OCaml and trying to understand the following code:

```
type 'a inL = __
```

What does mean two underscores in OCaml?
Where should I look to find the meaning odf the syntactical elements which are hard to google?

Comment: As far as I know it has no special meaning. It's a valid identifier though, so defining a type with that name will have it compile: `type __ = int type 'a inL = __`. Where did you find this? What's the surrounding context?

Comment: @glennsl Thanks, that exactly the information I've been looking for. It is a generated code.